# How could Salazar have expected his plan for the Chamber of Secrets to work?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, slytherin, chamber-of-secrets

As I understand it, there's only two possible interpretations of Salazar's plan for the Chamber of Secrets. Either:

1. His heir releases the monster and has it kill the unworthy in secret.
2. His heir releases the monster and acts publicly, aiming for a split that has the unworthy driven out.

However, both interpretations strike me as very ineffective plots. Situation #1 fails as it did in the books - the school gets shut down after a single death, and his plan ends largely unsuccessfully - and situation #2 fails as soon as somebody opposed to the plot either gets their hands on a rooster or kills the monster the old fashioned way.

So, under the assumption that I've not missed anything, how could Salazar have expected his plan for the Chamber of Secrets to work? His plot seems very ineffective.

Comment: Or maybe his plot is just a big f*ck you to the inhabitants of Hogwarts. Leave a monster in the basement and it'll probably eat someone eventually. Does every evil scheme need to be clever?

Comment: How is the school closing a failure? No more muggleborns...

Comment: @marcellothearcane No more pure bloods either.

Comment: Yes more pure bloods - as soon as the school is shut, put the big snake away and restart Hogwarts, with the heir of Slytherin at the helm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The basilisk can move about Hogwarts stealthily.

With a bit of caution, whoever commanded the basilisk would be able to have it move through the pipes without being seen. Until Harry and Ron went into the Chamber themselves, which they only could have done because Harry was a Parselmouth at the time, no one had actually seen the basilisk and remained in any sort of state to take action against it or its commander.

> “But how’s the Basilisk been getting around the place?’ said Ron. ‘A dirty great snake … Someone would’ve seen …’
>
> Harry, however, pointed at the word Hermione had scribbled at the foot of the page.
>
> ‘Pipes,’ he said. ‘Pipes … Ron, it’s been using the plumbing. I’ve been hearing that voice inside the walls …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 16 (The Chamber of Secrets)*</sup></sub>

The one commanding the basilisk may need to act relatively swiftly to rid Hogwarts of Muggle-borns because Hogwarts might decide to close due to the killings, but if they keep mainly to the pipes, it would minimize their risk of being caught or having the basilisk killed. Before the Chamber was accessed by pipes, it was accessed by magical tunnels, which would have served the same purpose of keeping the basilisk hidden from view.

> When first created, the Chamber was accessed through a concealed trapdoor and a series of magical tunnels. However, when Hogwarts’ plumbing became more elaborate in the eighteenth century (this was a rare instance of wizards copying Muggles, because hitherto they simply relieved themselves wherever they stood, and vanished the evidence), the entrance to the Chamber was threatened, being located on the site of a proposed bathroom. The presence in school at the time of a student called Corvinus Gaunt – direct descendant of Slytherin, and antecedent of Tom Riddle – explains how the simple trapdoor was secretly protected, so that those who knew how could still access the entrance to the Chamber even after newfangled plumbing had been placed on top of it. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Chamber of Secrets (Wizarding World website)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets)*</sup></sub>

Once the basilisk is kept concealed, all whoever was controlling it would really risk is Hogwarts closing before their task is done. If they work swiftly however, they should be able to complete it. Even should Hogwarts close, as it is the only magical school in Britain, it cannot stay closed forever. Reopening is nearly inevitable, and if the one commanding the basilisk was successful at killing them all before Hogwarts closed, it would reopen without Muggle-borns. If there are remaining Muggle-borns, they could simply restart their attack.

## Hogwarts would likely be rid of roosters first.

Also, before unleashing the basilisk, Tom Riddle killed the roosters that were at Hogwarts so there would be no roosters near. Anyone else commanding the basilisk, as long as they were reasonably intelligent, would similarly purge the roosters from Hogwarts before purging the Muggle-borns.

> “*‘The Basilisk flees only from the crowing of the rooster, which is fatal to it!’* he read aloud. ‘Hagrid’s roosters were killed! The heir of Slytherin didn’t want one anywhere near the castle once the Chamber was opened!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 16 (The Chamber of Secrets)*</sup></sub>

Once the roosters at Hogwarts were dealt with, the only risk would be that someone would bring a rooster back into Hogwarts. That would be unlikely, unless someone thought they knew what the monster was, which is also unlikely. No one, including Dumbledore, had deduced what the monster was when Tom Riddle unleashed it on Hogwarts until another Parselmouth happened to be at Hogwarts as well and heard it moving around the pipes.

Comment: A slight note: According to Rowling, the pipes weren't added until the 18th Century, when plumbing became more widespread in Muggle Britain with Wizarding Britain followed suit. Slytherin's original construction (ca. 10th-11th Centuries) consisted of a magical door and series of tunnels or passages; he wouldn't have conceived of the use of indoor plumbing 600+ years before it was available. https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets

Comment: "_The one commanding the basilisk may need to act relatively swiftly to rid Hogwarts of Muggle-borns because Hogwarts might decide to close due to the killings_" doesn't that surrender the point? Having the school closed is against Salazar's goal, and you've just admitted that it's difficult for the killings to take place without the school closing.

Comment: @Mal I wouldn't worry too much about the pipes point. After all, the plot of CoS relies on Hogwarts never having renovated that one bathroom.